# noreturn attribute across function call wrapper

Tags: c++, noreturn

Is it possible to make noreturn work together with a function call wrapper, like `std::invoke`:

```
#include <functional>

[[noreturn]] void foo()
    {std::terminate();}

int doStuff()
   {std::invoke(foo);}
```

This results in a warning, but `doStuff` will *not* return.